# combine 2 schemas in 1 XML file

Tags: xml, schema

I need to have descriptive info from the mods schema and technical info from the PBCore schema in ONE XML document. But no matter what order I put things in, I keep getting a well formedness error in my XML editor.
I have this prologue at the top of the XML doc:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<mods:modsCollection xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 
http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-6.xsd">
```

and this a little later in my XML doc:

```
<pbcoreCollection xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html 
http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example document showing this done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mods:modsCollection xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3
                      http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-6.xsd">
  <mods:mods>
    <mods:extension>
      <pbcoreCollection
        xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html
                            http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd">
        <pbcoreDescriptionDocument>
          <pbcoreIdentifier source="NOLA Code">AMEX000102</pbcoreIdentifier>
          <pbcoreTitle>American Experience: Radio Bikini</pbcoreTitle>
          <pbcoreDescription>In July 1946, the U.S. Navy...
                    later.</pbcoreDescription>
        </pbcoreDescriptionDocument>
      </pbcoreCollection>
    </mods:extension>
  </mods:mods>
</mods:modsCollection>
```

The trick is to assure you can insert the other-schema content where the parent schema allows. Basically, look at the XSD file for elements that can contain `mixed="true"` content:

http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-6.xsd

Comment: Thank you! This is very, very helpful.

Comment: What I really need to know now is how to create and XSLT that will combine the metadata for two different XML documents into one, merging together the information as it is in your example.